# Can the Visual Studio 2012 C++ Redistributable be installed automatically with a TFS Build?

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio

I have an ASP.Net project that's using the ClearScript.V8 library which relies on the Visual Studio 2012 C++ Redistributable to work. I'm faced with the prospect of having to install this on 50+ machines and I'm curious if I can get TFS to do it for me.

I realize this straddles somewhere between Stack Overflow and Server Fault so I'm asking on both sites.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do it, IMHO it is not a good idea. The account running the Build service should be a non-administrative account, which means that it has no permission to install anything.

This is a security best practice, I suggest to follow when possible.

Consider other alternatives for pushing changes, like Desired State Configuration (DSC) or remote Powershell.